# Which plan is the most loaded in KG

Tags: java

I have Class Passanger / Baggage  and Plane

Class Plane

I create a method inside the plane that should make the sum of KgPassangers + KgBaggages  so then i can use it to compare it to  the capacity to get the result i expect to.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Plane {
    private String name;
    private int sitPLaces;
    private int capacity;

    List<Passanger> passangers = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Baggage> baggage = new ArrayList<>();

    public Plane(String name, int sitPLaces, int capacity) {
        this.name = name;
        this.sitPLaces = sitPLaces;
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getSitPLaces() {
        return sitPLaces;
    }

    public void setSitPLaces(int sitPLaces) {
        this.sitPLaces = sitPLaces;
    }

    public int getCapacity() {
        return capacity;
    }

    public void setCapacity(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Plane{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", sitPLaces=" + sitPLaces +
                ", capacity=" + capacity +
                '}';
    }


    public void addPassanger(Passanger newPassanger) {
        if (capacity < passangers.size()) {
            // System.out.println("No space for more passangers");
        } else {
            // System.out.println("Welcome to board!");
        }
        passangers.add(newPassanger);
    }

    //todo you need sum of weight baggages and passengers to compare it
    public void addBaggage(Baggage newBaggage) {
        baggage.add(newBaggage);
    }

    public void addKgBaggage(Baggage newBaggage) {
        if (newBaggage.getWeigh() >= capacity) {
            System.out.println("Plane capacity is full!");

        } else{
            System.out.println("Welcome abord");
        }
    }

    public int getHowManyPassangersAreIn() {
        return passangers.size();
    }

    public void kgBaggage(Baggage newBaggage){
        if (baggage.get(0).getWeigh() != capacity){
            baggage.add(newBaggage);
            System.out.println("you can add more baggage");
        }
        if(baggage.get(0).getWeigh() >= capacity){
            baggage.add(newBaggage);
            System.out.println("Plane is to heavy");
        }
    }
    public int getkgBaggage(){
        return baggage.get(0).getWeigh();
    }
    public int getkgPassanger(){
        return baggage.get(0).getWeigh();
    }
    public int getKgBaggageandPassaanger(){
        return getkgPassanger() + getkgBaggage();
    }
    public void getKgAll(Baggage newBaggage){
        if(getkgPassanger()+getkgBaggage() > capacity){
            System.out.println("Plane is full");
        }
    }
}
```

This is  my main :

Seems that i am dooing something wrong.

```
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
   Plane plane1 = new Plane("Beoing", 350, 35000);
        plane1.addPassanger(new Passanger("Victor", 80));
        plane1.addPassanger(new Passanger("Stefan", 60));

        plane1.addBaggage(new Baggage("Kipling", 150));
        plane1.addBaggage(new Baggage("Kipling", 50));

        Plane plane2 = new Plane("Flig", 200, 1500);
        plane2.addPassanger(new Passanger("Mihai", 95));
        plane2.addPassanger(new Passanger("Rudy", 65));

        plane2.addBaggage(new Baggage("Kipling", 30));
        plane2.addBaggage(new Baggage("Kipling", 50));


        Plane plane3 = new Plane("Aly", 100, 3500);
        plane3.addPassanger(new Passanger("Vlad", 80));
        plane3.addPassanger(new Passanger("Vali", 160));
        plane3.addPassanger(new Passanger("Ionut", 50));


        plane3.addBaggage(new Baggage("Kipling", 100));
        plane3.addBaggage(new Baggage("Kipling", 300));
        plane3.addBaggage(new Baggage("Kipling", 200));

        List<Plane> planeList = List.of(plane1, plane2, plane3);
}
        Plane planeWithMostPassangers = getPlaneWithMostPassangers(planeList);
        System.out.println("In this plane are the most  passangers: " + planeWithMostPassangers);

    public static Plane getMostLoadedPLane(List<Plane> planeList) {
        Plane kgTotal = planeList.get(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < planeList.size(); i++) {
            if (planeList.get(i).getCapacity() >= kgTotal.getkgBaggage() + kgTotal.getkgPassanger() ){
                kgTotal = planeList.get(i);

            }
        }
        return kgTotal;
    }
}
```

Can somoane please tell me where i am going wrong ?
Thanks,

Comment: Why are you comparing capacity planeList.get(i).getCapacity() here? I guess you should be getting baggage weight and passenger weight when you are trying to find the most loaded plane

Answer (score 0):

You should not compare capacity when you're trying to find the most loaded plane. Compare actual weight in the for loop.

```java
public static Plane getMostLoadedPLane(List<Plane> planeList) {
        Plane kgTotal = planeList.get(0);
        for (int i = 1; i < planeList.size(); i++) {
             Plane currPlane = planeList.get(i);
            if (currPlane.getKgBaggageandPassaanger()  >= kgTotal.getKgBaggageandPassaanger() ){
                kgTotal = currPlane;

            }
        }
        return kgTotal;
    }
```

Comment: Seems that  i do not get the good result :(, i supposed to get  plane 3 but i get always first plane .

Comment: @BecaliNr1 your getKgBaggae and getKgPassanger methods are wrong, you should return total weight of the list rather than just the first element.

Comment: I have figure it out in the end. I just create 2 methods  to go through  the Plaine list and get kg passanger and kg baggage and then I combine them. Thanks for help